# Need help creating separate variables from these 2 objects in the arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, numbers

// I wanted to create a variable to hold the month and a variable that hold the number...

```
var finances = [
['Jan-1999', 867886],
['Feb-1999', 984653],
['Mar-1999', 322012],
['Apr-1999', -69417],
['May-1999', 310503],
['Jun-1999', 522857],
['Jul-1999', 1033096],
['Aug-1999', 604885],
['Sep-1999', -216386],
['Oct-1999', 477532],
['Nov-1999', 893810]];
```

Comment: You don't have objects, you have nested arrays. Anyway, you can create your two variables using the `map()` method.

Comment: Or you could loop over the array once, and push `element[0]` to one array and `element[1]` to the other array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `map()` that returns a new array with the result of a function applied to your initial array. In this case your functions would either select the first element of the subarray (the date), or the second element (the number).

```js
var finances = [
['Jan-1999', 867886],
['Feb-1999', 984653],
['Mar-1999', 322012],
['Apr-1999', -69417],
['May-1999', 310503],
['Jun-1999', 522857],
['Jul-1999', 1033096],
['Aug-1999', 604885],
['Sep-1999', -216386],
['Oct-1999', 477532],
['Nov-1999', 893810]];

const dates = finances.map((e) => e[0]);
const numbers = finances.map((e) => e[1]);
console.log(dates);
console.log(numbers);
```